# Save Illustrator file from text in the file using Illustrator actions

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting, actions

I'm saving a bunch of files and I would like to save them using selected text from the file using actions. Right now, I'm able to select the text and copy and paste in the file. But when the save as dialog box comes up, it won't paste the text.

I either need to convert the selected text to highlighted and then copy and paste or figure out a command that will copy text to the clipboard so I can paste it in.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Not possible to do with actions time to learn scripting.

Comment: I've been working with a lot of scripts in Illustrator and InDesign, but I'm relatively new to it. Any suggestions on some script to do this?